# P/Invoke, c#: unsigned char losing a byte

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, unsigned-char

Im working towards a dll file for a software's SDK and i'm trying to call a function to get information about the host of the software.

there are two unsigned char variables(HostMachineAddress, HostProgramVersion) in the struct the function wants and it seems like i "loose" the last byte when i try to call it from c#... if I change the SizeConst in the c# struct below to 5 i do get the missing byte, however it causes the other variable looses data.

Could someone help me find a way to solve this issue? also trying to use a class instead of struct causes system.stackoverflow error

C# Struct

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct sHostInfo
{
    public int bFoundHost;
    public int LatestConfirmationTime;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
    public string szHostMachineName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)]
    public string HostMachineAddress;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 128)]
    public string szHostProgramName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 4)]
    public string HostProgramVersion;
}
```

C#

```
[DllImport("Cortex_SDK.dll")]
public static extern int GetHostInfo(out sHostInfo pHostInfo);
```

Comment: Why are HostProgramVersion and szHostProgramName swapped in your C# code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your C# struct's layout is different from the C++ one (HostProgramVersion should be last).

Also for strings marshalled as `ByValTStr` use `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]`.

The problem with the missing last byte may be that the marshaller tries to append null to your string (as in null-terminated string). Try to use `sbyte[]`+`ByValArray` instead of a string.

Comment: +1 Also, I'd always specify `StructLayoutAttribute.Pack` even though it's not relevant here.  A good habit to get into.

Comment: sorry my mistake regarding the swapped variables, however that didn't solve the issue i'm afraid, Also added the Charset.Ansi.

Comment: @Tistatos: Looking at your code again, it seems you are storing an IPv4 address/4-digit prog.version? That means the 4-char arrays should really `sbyte` arrays?!

Comment: Yes It stores the IP adress for the computer hosting the Software. so bascially what i needed was the "ByValArray" Thank you